# Dom background color manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, dom, deployment

I'm trying to change the background color for every other paragraph in my html file. I'm using a loop for this to reduce redundancy. It's not working for me tho whatever I'm doing. Any suggestions on how to do this easier?

The JS logic:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Add event listener to the button
  document.getElementById('changeBackgroundBtn').addEventListener('click', changeBackground);
  
  function changeBackground() {
    console.log('changeBackground() called');
    // Get the div containing paragraphs
    const parasDiv = document.getElementById('paras');

    // Get all paragraphs inside the div
    const paragraphs = parasDiv.getElementsByTagName('p');

    // Loop through paragraphs and change background color for every other paragraph
    for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
      // Check if the index is odd (every other paragraph)
      if (i % 2 === 0) {
        // Toggle background color between lightblue and white
        paragraphs[i].style.backgroundColor =
          paragraphs[i].style.backgroundColor === 'lightblue' ? '' : 'lightblue';
      }
    }
}});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Basic DOM Manipulation</h1>
  <p>
    <button id="changeBackgroundBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
  Change Background
</button>
```

Comment: The code shown is producing an error because there is no element with the `id` value `"paras"`.  Are you observing that same error in your browser console when you test?

Comment: presumably simply using CSS and `nth-of-type` is not an option for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment above, you could use the `nth-of-type` property in css to target every 2nd `p` element. The button below simply toggles a class on the parent container and the css rule does the rest.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',e=>{
  e.target.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('colours');
})
```

```css
p{
  background:white;
  padding:1rem;
  font-family:monospace;
}

.container.colours p:nth-of-type(even){
  background:lightblue;
  color:darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed dapibus leo in diam bibendum, a bibendum tellus congue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

  <p>Praesent pellentesque fringilla pharetra. Suspendisse eget felis eget erat viverra placerat. Aliquam id tincidunt ligula, in cursus nunc.</p>

  <p>nteger pretium magna nec arcu pellentesque ullamcorper. Pellentesque rhoncus nunc sed urna tempor, sed pretium nunc sollicitudin.</p>

  <p>Duis placerat erat eu odio finibus dignissim. Duis rhoncus, velit non aliquam elementum, risus arcu sollicitudin sapien, eu egestas purus ex vel risus.</p>

  <p>Etiam lobortis ligula sit amet purus ornare facilisis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;</p>

  <p>Donec bibendum pharetra sapien id tincidunt. Proin metus ante, pellentesque vel dui sed, lobortis ultricies justo. Proin accumsan ultrices ex, at aliquam erat lobortis vel.</p>

  <p>Vivamus rutrum leo urna, eget porta neque condimentum sed. Nunc fermentum ullamcorper mattis. Sed a malesuada velit. Aenean porttitor sagittis neque, consectetur pharetra enim tristique eget.</p>

  <p>Nam et convallis felis. Maecenas sit amet viverra ex. Suspendisse potenti. Donec dictum faucibus gravida. Duis molestie lorem sed turpis tincidunt rhoncus. Vivamus nunc nulla, sagittis sed lectus non, fermentum placerat massa. Praesent ac tristique sapien.</p>

  <p>Aenean tristique aliquet lacinia. Curabitur vitae bibendum libero, vitae rhoncus nunc. Proin lobortis, ipsum a venenatis blandit, justo augue placerat odio, quis pretium tortor ipsum nec felis.</p>
</div>


<button>Change</button>
```